# Automatically removing duplicates or just not creating them in uitableview from passed data

Tags: uitableview, uiwebview, nsmutablearray, duplicates

I have a `uiwebview` that sends its loaded page url to a `uitableview` to retain a history of visited sites. It works great except that a few sites pause loading briefly which causes another url reference to be created. Try going to redmondpie.com and I end up with 50 redmondpie.com links in my visited list. Am I doing this wrong or is there a code I can use to block the link being recreated over and over while the page loads. I guess the best option would be something like if the url exists right next to the one being created then don't create it, or something. Heres how it's loaded now.

```
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {


urlField.text = [[[[self webView]request] URL] absoluteString];

{
    NSMutableArray *history = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]    arrayForKey:@"History"] mutableCopy];
    if (!history) {
        history = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    NSString *newString  = 
    [urlField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://" withString:@""]



    urlField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", newString];

    [history addObject:newString];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:history forKey:@"History"];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the last object in the array to see if it is the same before adding it by changing this:

```
[history addObject:newString];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:history forKey:@"History"];
```

to this:

```
if (![newString isEqualToString:(NSString *)[history lastObject]]) {
    [history addObject:newString];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:history forKey:@"History"];
}
```